# Uncaught exception: This class is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nib, nsunknownkeyexception

I'm following [a tutorial titled "Swift Tutorial for iOS : NSFileManager Persisting Data"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PJtUQ6L_mc), and I've encountered an error around or after the 29 minute mark. When I try running it on the iOS simulator, I receive the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theLoadMethod.'

Obviously based off the error, I'm thinking the problem is my `theLoadMethod`. Here is *all* the code I wrote as part of this project in the ViewController:

```
let theDocumentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let theFileName     = "/theUserFile.txt"
let thePath         = theDocumentsFolder.stringByAppendingString(theFileName)


class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var theLabel: UILabel!

// The save method
@IBAction func theSaveMethod(sender: AnyObject) {
    var name        = nameTextField.text
    var lastName    = lastNameTextField.text
    var age         = ageTextField.text

    var theString   =   "The user's information is: \(name), \(lastName), \(age)"

    let theFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if !theFileManager.fileExistsAtPath(thePath) {

        var writeError:NSError?
        let fileToBeWritten = theString.writeToFile(thePath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &writeError)

        if writeError == nil {
            println("No errors. Added: \(theString)")
        } else {
            println("Encountered an error. Error is: \(writeError)")
        }

    } else {
        println("File already exists")
    }

    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    lastNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    ageTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

@IBAction func theLoadMethod(sender: AnyObject) {
    let infoFromFile:String = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(thePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!

    theLabel.text = infoFromFile
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? As far as I'm aware, all my iOS on screen elements are correctly named and linked.

Comment: This is normally caused by a link from your storyboard to a non existent property. Double check all the links from objects in your storyboard

Comment: @Paulw11 How do I do that? Just look at the names of each of the object names in the storyboard and make sure they match my IBOutlet declarations?

Comment: Select each of your controls, text fields, etc and check their referencing outlets in the inspector window.

Comment: @Paulw11. There's only 6 elements: 3 text fields, 2 buttons, & 1 label. Each referencing outlet looks good. The buttons are declared as IBAction functions and the rest are IBOutlets...

Comment: You can control or right click on your storyboard and open as source and the use cmd-f to search for theLoadMethod. Something is referring to theat property name

Comment: @Paulw11, well, I fixed it. I deleted the links of one of the buttons and relinked it, and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Paulw11 If you want to add your comments as an answer, I'll accept it as correct and resolved.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if your button name is, for example "Click This Button" then you will have to label the declaration "clickThisButton" or something like that.  Then it should work.  I had a button called "Login" and when I tried to use the declaration "loginButton" it failed, but then I changed it to "login" and it worked.  Pretty wacky.  I'm not sure how to go around this.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This is normally caused by a link from your storyboard to a non existent property. Double check all the links from objects in your storyboard. Also if you have changed the name or spelling of a property or method it can still have a reference to the old one.

Comment: Can search in project navigator for the offending outlet (referenced in debugger) and it will be flagged up. Delete by hitting the x next to it (not by selecting and hitting delete button via navigator).

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/52021/how-do-i-fix-the-issue-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-in-xcode-6/

i got same issue and already fix, maybe this link can help other people too

Comment: This can also happen after copying a scene/view on a storyboard and relinking to a different view controller class. You'll need to review the outlets for each control on the view and delete the old ones in the Connections Inspector.

Comment: The Lord bless your born and unborn children.

Comment: I tried everything here multiple times. In the end, I created a new View and ViewController to replace the old one, deleted the problematic one, and the issue was resolved. I also spent waaayyy too much time on this problem.

Answer (score 61):

For those who are facing the same issue and has already made sure that the IBOutlets are alright (at least look fine in Interface Builder):
make sure you have the module (see the attached image) for your view controller set to "Current - $(PROJECT_NAME)".
[image]

Comment: Sad to hear. But what exactly doesn't work? Moreover, the answer itself has never been presented as a cure-all.

Comment: @Rocotilos, if you have multiple targets in your project, the module field should have the same value as the name of the target containing your .xib/.storyboard file.

Comment: Initially I didn't think this answer worked - but just found out that I had to "refresh" the class (by re-entering the class name), and that added the placeholder text to the module field. Thanks!

Comment: You are talking about the File's Owner right ? Well I type the class name again, but the module stills says: "None"

Comment: @omarojo, yes it's all about the file's owner. I assume, the module remains empty (and the drop-down list is empty as well) because you haven't set the "Defines module" (at Your target -> Build Settings) flag on your target to true. In other words: make sure there's at least one *module* in your project.

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan but is this necessary ? Ive never setup that flag ever in any of my projects ever.

Comment: @omarojo, all depends on your needs. It's not necessary. Maybe there is another problem with your Xib/Storyboard file. My answer doesn't cover all the possible cases.

Comment: +1 for solving my problem. This has been pissing me off for freaking hours. Why the default for a newly added view controller is none I'll never guess if this is what happens.

Comment: thanks this fixed my problem

Comment: Thanks for explaining well! This helped me because I was using the same class for two different targets, and selecting "Inherit Module from Target" fixed this issue

Answer (score 23):

I was having a similar issue. I had changed the fields required by the user and renamed a couple of fields.

I made all the necessary changes in parse (dropped and added columns). The backend was not the problem.

Your interface builder source code still contains the old attributes.

To solve right click on main.storyboard -> Open As -> Source Code....look for the fields that you removed or renamed ...delete or modified them ...it depends changes you made.

in your case did you rename theLoadMethod from something else?

hope this helps someone out there.

Cheers!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!! I was panicking because I totally broke my project and could NOT figure out what the problem was. I tried undoing a crapton and it just kept happening even when I went back to where I knew it was working. Without your post I don't know what I would have done.

Comment: @SomeGuy haha no problem man. I spent a few hours trying to figure out it. smh

Comment: @Ronaldoh1 Thank you very much for the tip : "right click on main.storyboard -> Open As -> Source Code....look for the fields that you removed or renamed ...delete or modified them." That helped me to find the cursed button that I had deleted from the storyboard and the coder version controller but still gave me headaches for an hour till I read your tip.

Comment: Though, this solution helped, but there is a better answer -
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8087739/961143

Comment: THANK YOU. What was happening to me is that it was assinging any outlets to File's Owner instead of to the source directly. All I did was open as source and deleted the file owner's class name. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks, this was brilliant and it worked for me.

Comment: wow that could have taken ages to find, perfect!

Comment: thanks for exposing this. Solved my issue :)

Comment: haha no problem guys - seems to be an on going issue

Comment: You are a legend!

Answer (score 3):

Simply navigate to your Main.storyboard code by right clicking and selecting the source code tab, then remove the previous entry which is stored (the application stores previous entries, just remove that).

Comment: Thank you! This is what actually worked! I'm coming from a programmer background (C++, Python, Java, ...) and while I like all the nice UI features, like dragging from your Storybody to you code, I feel unease because I don't really know what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered with a similar error. I solved the problem by means of changing Build Location to Custom in the settings of XCode after updating it. Just set this field to 'Relative to Workspace' and that's it.